# Codeigniter Datamapper - multilevel page navigation

Tags: php, codeigniter, datamapper, codeigniter-datamapper

I am using "DataMapper, OverZealous Edition" for my current project. I have to make multilevel sub-page navigation in my project, i.e like

```
       Page-A
         - Page-A1
         - Page-A2
           - Page-A22
       Page-B
```

Presently there is no sub-page concept in my project. Previously I have created "pages" table. The page table have also a relationship with "users" table to determine the user permission to access this page.

Here are the current "users" and "pages" table structures as follows:

```
       ------------         --------------      ---------------
          users               pages_users            pages
       ------------         --------------      ---------------
        - id                  - id                   - id
        - name                - user_id              - pg_name 
        - email               - page_id              - pg_status
        - password
```

Table Relationship:

```
         users                             pages 
    --------------------------         ------------------------    
     $has_many = array('page');        $has_many= array('user');
```

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question but for it seems like what you need is to create a hierarchy.  Your pages table should have a parent_page field that links to the parent page.  If it is at the root level it should have a null parent.  Then you would create a relationship that links one page to one parent page.

Does this make sense?